# Resize events on Safari (iOS 7) under pinch zoom, only in landscape?

Tags: javascript, safari, resize, ios7, pinchzoom

I'm trying to shoot a problem with a change of behavior we've seen in the iOS 7 release that perhaps others have run into.

We have some code that handles resize events in our website. The way this should ideally work is that it won't get executed if you're doing a zoom (e.g. a pinch zoom on a phone), but would be fired if you resized the browser window, for example.

What we're finding is that on our iOS 7 devices, safari frequently fires javascript resize events when we are doing a pinch zoom. This doesn't happen all the time, and seems to only happen in landscape mode. Our iOS6 devices didn't do that, and neither do any of the Android devices we have on hand. These have two ill effects:

1) It seems to cause a page "jump," i.e. it will suddenly reposition the page, usually to the upper-left corner. Note that this will happen even if we don't have a resize event handler.

I don't think it's our page layout. We've been particularly careful to avoid things that can cause behavior like fractional pixels and percentage heights and widths. Also, we can eliminate this behavior by setting the viewport width (via META tag) to 700px or less. Plus, we don't see any such issues in profile, as noted. (we aren't setting any other viewport settings, so that's not the issue; and setting "width=client-width" doesn't help us.

2) It seems that in the resize handler, it doesn't really give us the expected values for window.innerWidth; i.e. I'll be zoomed in and it will give me a larger-than-expected value. For instance, I usually use something like this to determine if we're zooming:

abs(1 - document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth) < 0.02

but that doesn't seem to do the trick here.

Unfortunately, we will have to work around this, since the logic in our resize does a page reformatting. This page is essentially a custom online report that's frequently viewed landscape style; we can't just tell our users not to zoom or rotate their phone ;-)

Has anyone run into these problems? And if so, how did you work around it?

As an aside: has anyone found that the latest 7.0.3 safari update sometimes doesn't let you clear the javascript alerts (i.e. the "OK" button on the alert doesn't work, resulting in safari hanging)? I know there was a problem with alerts that was to have been fixed with the iOS 7.0.3 update, but perhaps there are other issues I don't know about. When we get in this state we have to restart the device.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we made the "page jump" in landscape mode go away for us. It isn't a "good" solution, in that we don't know why it works. We set the viewport meta tag to the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920 height=1080"/>
```

I doubt these particular numbers are "magic" - it seems that so long as both width and height is specified, the page jumps go away. Perhaps without the height, there are errors calculating the height from the device aspect ratio that causes page re-layouts? (see Kamen Bundev's post about erroneous reported window heights in landscape mode in http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-mobile/application/ios-7-safari-window-height-.aspx; unfortunately I haven't found anything else referencing this particular bug).

We've found the issue seems to be associated with HTML having tables laid out side-by-side. I've done experiments and as long as the viewport width is large enough to allow the tables to sit next to one another, you're likely to see the bug.